# How to format the file containing json objects to json array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, npm

I have json file containing multiple objects in a single file I want to convert them to JSON array how to do this javascript. My overall goal is generate a CSV file out of it.

Here is the sample file content,

```
{
  Name:"nom1",
  Cities:['city1','city2']
}
{
  Name:"nom2",
  Cities:['city4','city5']
}
```

Note above is the  data dump it is not correct format yet , I want to convert it to following format

```
var data = [ { Name:"nom1", Cities:['city1','city2'] }, { Name:"nom2", Cities:['city3','city4'] } ]};
```

Then pass it to the below script.

I have thousands of such objects in a single file. I want to generate CSV data as follows

**|Name|Cities|**

|nom1|city1 |

|nom1|city2 |

|nom2|city3 |

|nom2|city4 |

I am using node javascript to achieve this ,

```
const { Parser, transforms: { unwind } } = require('json2csv');

const data = {
  Name:"nom1",
  Cities:['city1','city2']
}
const fields = ['Name'];
const transforms = [unwind({ paths: ['features'] })];

const json2csvParser = new Parser({ fields, transforms });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);

console.log(csv);
```

Comment: Where did you get that "example file"? Because without variables assignment, it's not even meaningful JS: those objects will immediately get thrown away.

Comment: That is raw data dump I have , I need to convert them into an array of objects and pass it into my script

Comment: var data = [  { Name:"nom1", Cities:['city1','city2'] }, { Name:"nom2", Cities:['city3','city4'] } ]};

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a script

Comment: Then please update your post, don't put "new" or "updated" code in comments. Right now, the first block of code you're showing isn't really anything: no tool would dump to plain JS format (because it's not JSON yet), but even if they did, they wouldn't be dumping the code you're showing because you can't _do_ anything with that data. So: what tools are you using?

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be to read the file line-by-line and replace the (regex) pattern `^[}]$` (lines with nothing but a closing brace) with `},` ( skip the replacement for the last line). Assemble the lines to a single string, enclose it with square brackets, and call `JSON.stringify(...)`.

Comment: Thanks collapsar, I am not that familiar to writing scripts I am learning them, can you create a mock script please

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have updated my question . I am not sure what tool was used to generate the data dump

Comment: I'm a bit confused about that statement: do you not know where you even got this data?

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick with the file exactly like the one you presented:

`log-parser.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs')

async function fileToArray (file) {
  const fileContent = await fs.promises.readFile(file)
  const singleLined = fileContent
                .toString()
                .replace(/\n/g, '')
                .replace(/\}\{/g, '},{')
                .replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":')
                .replace(/'/g, '"')

  console.log(singleLined)
  const array = JSON.parse(`[${singleLined}]`)
  console.log(array)
}

fileToArray(process.argv[2])
```

```sh
node log-parser.js my-log-file.log
```

Comment: Hi Mestre San, When I pass {
  Name:"nom1",
  Cities:['city1','city2']
}
{
  Name:"nom2",
  Cities:['city4','city5']
}

Comment: I get  } "Cities":['city4','city5']

Comment: Hi @karansys, I've created a gist with all the steps for you to reproduce the solution
https://gist.github.com/danielsan/235959b92c7b6425dc6d94f154a3c654